# How to setup ansible_local with vagrant 1.7.4?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have this configuration of my host machine:

```
hedin@home:~/123$ lsb_release -rcd
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
hedin@home:~/123$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.2
```

I'm trying to deploy my guest with ansible_local provision. This is my Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # Run Ansible from the Vagrant VM
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end
end
```

When I try to deploy it I receiving this output:

```
hedin@home:~/123$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The '' provisioner could not be found.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show your playbook file so your issue can be fully reproduced ?

Comment: My playbook is empty.

Comment: Issue was caused by Vagrant version. When I upgraded to 1.8.5. it was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant v1.7 versions have a bug causing this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ./vagrant_1.7.4_x86_64.deb
(Reading database ... 57030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./vagrant_1.7.4_x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking vagrant (1:1.7.4) over (1:1.7.3) ...
Setting up vagrant (1:1.7.4) ...
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The 'ansible_local' provisioner could not be found.
```

Upgrade to the current version 1.8.5 (or at least 1.8.0):

```
$ sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.8.0_x86_64.deb
(Reading database ... 57030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack vagrant_1.8.0_x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking vagrant (1:1.8.0) over (1:1.7.4) ...
Setting up vagrant (1:1.8.0) ...
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
```